# Convergence of the sequnce and series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

so I'm preparing for my calculus exam and I have no ideea how to solve this sequence and also compute the series.
[here is the function](http://www.symbolab.com/solver/limit-calculator/%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%5Cleft(%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B%5Cleft(n%2B1%5Cright)%5E%7B2%7D%7D-%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7Bn%5E%7B2%7D%7D%5Cright)%5E%7B2%7D/?origin=button)

I have tried to conjugate, to force the common factor out, and somehow I got 0 but It just seems wrong and I have no ideea how to compute the series . Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using that $$x-y=\frac{x^3-y^3}{x^2+xy+y^2}$$ you have

$$\begin{array}{rcl}\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2}-\sqrt[3]{n^2}&=& \displaystyle\frac{(n+1)^2-n^2}{\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{n^2(n+1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{n^4}}\\ & = & \displaystyle\frac{2n+1}{\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^4}+\sqrt[3]{n^2(n+1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{n^4}}\\ & = & \displaystyle\frac{2+1/n}{\sqrt[3]{\frac{(n+1)^4}{n^3}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{(n+1)^2}{n}}+\sqrt[3]{n}} \end{array}$$

that converges to zero. Thus

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} (\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2}-\sqrt[3]{n^2})^2=0.$$

With respect to the convergence of the series, note that

$$\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2}-\sqrt[3]{n^2}\ge \frac{2}{3\sqrt[3]{n}}.$$ Thus,

$$(\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2}-\sqrt[3]{n^2})^2\ge \frac{4}{9\sqrt[3]{n^2}}\ge \frac{4}{9n}.$$ This shows that the series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{\to\infty}\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2}-\sqrt[3]{n^2}\cdot{\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^4}+\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2n^2}+\sqrt[3]{n^4}\over \sqrt[3]{(n+1)^4}+\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2n^2}+\sqrt[3]{n^4}}\\
={(n+1)^2-n^2\over \sqrt[3]{(n+1)^4}+\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2n^2}+\sqrt[3]{n^4}}\\
={2n+1\over\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^4}+\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2n^2}+\sqrt[3]{n^4}}.$$

Can you get it from here?

Comment: Thank's for that comment ,that was the point in which I got lost, but mfl answared to my problem